# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ui-calendarProvider <- ui-calendar

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using Angular 1.5 and have been trying to use AngularUI Router but without any luck.
Whenever I add a div element with ui-calendar such as:
`<div ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" ng-model="{}"></div>`,

I get errors like:
`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ui-calendarProvider <- ui-calendar`
I haven't used this provider nor injected it anywhere in my code.

Angular-ui-calendar's version is 1.0.2. I have included on package.json
`"angular-ui-bootstrap": "^1.3.2",
"angular-ui-calendar": "^1.0.2",`

What is the error I am encountering?

Answer (score 0):

Including `"angular-ui-calendar": "^1.0.2"` alone does nothing, I am guessing you didn't inject `ui.calendar` in your app. should look something like this

`angular.module('App', ['ui.calendar'])`

Go ahead and refer to the documentation https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar

Answer (score 0):

inject ui-calendar in your app module.